# Where can I find historical daily term repo data?

Tags: fixed-income, bloomberg, treasuries

DTCC appears to provide historical o/n repo data for US Treasuries but does not do so for term repo data. If I want to analyze the term repo curve, where would I be able to find historical term repo data?

More specifically, I'm wondering if I would be able to find term repo rate data for specific OTR US Treasuries in any data provider?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Markit Securities Finance](http://www.markit.com/product/pricing-data-securities-finance). If you are an academic, then your institution might have subscribed to it via [WRDS](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu).